# How to programmatically retrieve item version history from client?

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, web-services, version-history

Using server-side code I can access List Item version history using SPListItem.Versions.

Is there a way to programmatically access the same information from the client?

I am happy to use either the Client Object Model, SharePoint Web Services or any other mechanism.

Note:

1. I am trying to access this information remotely - please don't answer with server-side code.
2. I am not trying to access FileVersionHistory - I'm after history for the ListItem itself.
3. Custom web service is not an option.

Comment: i wanna ask you about this topic, can i use method as GetVersionCollection() to get field that changed and in which version this field changed.
GetVersionCollection() return value of data changed between versions for specified field,
but how can i get the value changed with the number of version to this field.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at my answer provided to very similar question:

[Get meta data from a previous version of a document through webservice in MOSS 2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20019/get-meta-data-from-a-previous-version-of-a-document-through-webservice-in-moss-2/20022#20022)

Using web service and [Lists.GetVersionCollection Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getversioncollection%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is (as far as I know) only available option. So you need to call it for each field of your item.

Client object model is not an option.

**UPDATED**

To get all versions of version field you just need to call GetVersionCollection method on version field by passing it's internal name `_UIVersionString`

Simple code snippet:

```
ListProxy.Lists lists = new Lists();
lists.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
XmlNode versions = lists.GetVersionCollection("{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx}", 
                                                       "n", "_UIVersionString");
foreach(XmlNode version in versions.ChildNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(version.Attributes["_UIVersionString"].Value);
}
```

Comment: @GregSansom: It provides. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: That is your choice and it really depends on your specific application needs. I would not be comfortable with HTML parsing like you suggested. Anyway it is strange that better alternative doesn't exist.

Comment: I was breaking my head all day to find a solution through COM. It is surprising to know that MSFT has not provided that option using COM. You dead straight answer helped me to save further time I was about to waste in this.